# How to copy contents of array from another method into an array within the main method?

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I have an array I created that holds the contents of a file. This array is not in my main method, but another method. I am having trouble figuring out how to copy the array holding the file contents into an array within my main method so I can manipulate/append the information from there. I'm getting an error saying that it can't find the variable dataPieces. Can someone please help me figure this out? Is this even the best way to work with a file so that I can show the user the information and let them append it?
Thanks

```
   /**
Add in javadoc comments
*/


//import statements
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Try { 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String dataHolder[] = createFile();
        System.out.println(dataHolder);
    }

    public static String[] createFile(){
        //create file holding inventory information
        String dataPieces[] = new String[10];
        try{
            PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("inventory.txt");
            outputFile.println("3000.0");
            outputFile.println("Lamps 15.3 400");
            outputFile.println("Chairs 19.95 250");
            outputFile.print("Desks 95.0 300");
            int i =0;
            outputFile.close();

            File myFile = new File("inventory.txt");
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

            while(inputFile.hasNext() && i<dataPieces.length){
                dataPieces[i] = inputFile.next();
                i++;
            }
            inputFile.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("File cannot be created."); //what to say???????????<<<<<<<<
        }
        return dataPieces;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `createFile()` method already returns an array, so your main method should just assign that array to a variable :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] dataHolder = createFile();
    ...
}
```

There's no reason to call `createFile()` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You have something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<dataHolder.length; i++){
    dataHolder[i] = createFile(dataPieces);
}
```

Here you are trying to create inventory.txt file 10 times after that reading the same 10 times in a loop as above which is going to return you the same data.

So your method `createFile` is returning an array i.e. dataPieces, you could just change your for loop to something like:

```
dataHolder = createFile();
for(int i=0; i<dataHolder.length; i++){
    ...do something with dataPieces which is referred by dataHolder now.
}
```

There by reading and writing file just once and then operating on array further in another method.